# could not send the notification using topic messaging

Tags: php

could not send the notification using topic messaging. Here i am attached the code. Please check it. it runs fine on the postman. But could not get the notification.

```
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$headers = [
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];

 if($_POST['send_to']=='topic'){
    $fcmNotification = array(
        'to' => '/topics/'.$topic,
        'notification' => $dataToSentNotification,
    );
 }
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You ought to put the whole curl code inside of your if block, otherwise `$fcmNotification` won't be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [curl_errno function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) to get the specific error, code as follow:

```php
$error_msg = NULL;
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
if ($error_msg !== NULL) {
    print_r($error_msg);
}
```

As **aynber** says, add the whole `curl` sentences inside `if` or what do you expect if `$fcmNotification` is empty or null?